# Storing and counting in redis

Tags: redis

How do I store this in Redis?

```
+------+---------------+
| val1 | val2          |
+------+---------------+
|  51  | Urbis orbi    |
|  77  | Occaecati     |
|  51  | Ea eligendi   |
|  77  | Consequasit   |
|  51  | Hic unde      |
+------+---------------+
```

Then, how do I count it in Redis?
e.g.

```
select count() as count from table where val1 = '51';
```

Comment: I see we have a lot of people full of themselves today - that minus one. Zero class, itchy finger and yellow streak down someone's back - usually go together, right? Not even enough 'courage' to post a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `val1` may have multiple `val2` related to it. So you can use Redis `Lists` where `val1` values will be `KEY`s and `val2` values will be elements in respective list.

Equivalent of `insert` query can be

```
LPUSH val1 val2
```

Equivalent of `select count` query can be

```
LLEN val1
```